# What's the best algorithm to find a missing number between two sorted numbers?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, sequence

Okay, so here's an example:

We have an array `[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15]`

And we need to find the number that would fit between two numbers if this were sorted. It should help create a sequence of 3 numbers in the array, at the very least. We can assume there's only one missing number.

The answer in this case would be `8`. I got an idea as to how to brute force this in python using the `in` operator, but it's not very efficient.

```
def find_missing_number(arr):
    for num in arr:
        if (
                num in arr and
                num + 1 not in arr and
                num + 2 in arr
        ):
            return num + 1
```

Any language solutions are appreciated.

Comment: So essentially you're looking for two consecutive numbers in a sorted array with distance two?

Comment: exactly. idk how to go about implementing an efficient solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in C++ 17,

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v1 {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15};

    auto const it = std::adjacent_find(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                    [] (auto const a, auto const b) {
                    return b - a == 2;
                    } );

    if (it == v1.end()) {
            std::cout << "no matching\n";
    } else {
            std::cout << "the missing number: " << 1 + *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with c++ syntax, but i think i get the logic. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look for consecutive numbers with a distance of two:

```
def find_missing_number(arr):
    arr = sorted(arr)  # you'll only need this, if arr is not yet sorted
    for a, b in zip(arr, arr[1:]):
        if b - a == 2:
            return a + 1
```

Comment: this is great. wasn't familiar with the zip syntax, but it's quite handy with this problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it fast by using a set. And remove the pointless `num in arr` check (that's always true, since you're doing `for num in arr`).

```
def find_missing_number(arr):
    s = set(arr)
    for num in arr:
        if (num + 1 not in s) and (num + 2 in s):
            return num + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic that I would suggest is same.
For num = least to max least = 1 and max = 15 in this example

Iterate and see if the loop , and loop + 2 are in the array and loop+1 is not in the array